# Поисковая система на Java

Tags: поиск, java

Есть порядка 100-ни сайтов среди которых нужно устроить поиск, ну и проиндексовать их предварительно. То есть нужно написать полноценную поисковую систему с ботом и индексацией на Java. Может кто описать или дать ссылку на информацию, где описывается принцип работы поисковой системы, ее строение, алгоритмы поиска и индексации. Любая информация будет уместна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам пригодится библиотека для полнотекстового поиска [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). Она достаточно распространена (а потому хорошо поддерживается), о чем говорит хотя бы выпуск соответствующей "... in Action" и список [Powered By](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/PoweredBy). Она, впрочем, ориентирована именно на индексацию и поиск непосредственно в данном ей содержимом: "crawling", например, необходимо будет совершать самому (или  с помощью сторонней библиотеки).

Comment: Lucene - то, что нужно. Спасибо!